# I am seeing the runtime error message "1004"

Tags: excel, vba

I am seeing "Run-time Error 1004" at `lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row` in my code:

```
Sub copycolumns()
Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = "Algiers" Then
Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 2)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 3)
End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Can you help?

Comment: `x1Up` should be `xlUp` it should be lower case L not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a worksheet object, and `xlUp` is not equal to `x1Up`(your code has a typo i.e. digit 1).

use below line

```
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

instead of

```
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
```

Full code

```
Sub RoundedRectangle2_Click()
Dim lastrow, erow As Long
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = "Algiers" Then
Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Copy

erow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 2)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 3)
End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

**Alternatively**, you can use below line to find the rows count

```
rows_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))
```

Comment: You the Man Raju!! So simple and so effective. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @PhilipConnell, Good. If the issue is resolved then, you can close the question by accepting the answer. [Accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Hi Raju It worked fine yesterday but now it giving Run-time 424 for Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Columns().AutoFit` instead of `Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit`

Comment: Thank you Raju. This has worked. This was the easy part. I am very new to VBA. Thank you for your kind support. My next goal is a bit more Complex. I hope you can also be of assistance

Comment: @PhilipConnell, as the issue got resolved I suggest you to close the question by selecting 'accept answer'. If you have any further issues, raise a new question. Raising a new question will get attention from multiple users. Have a great day.

Comment: I would Love to give you some Rep points Raju how does one accept an answer on Stackover Flow

Comment: @PhilipConnell, you just did, which resulted +15 to me, +2 to you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Awesome. Have a Great Day. Much Respect from Dublin Ireland ;-)