# How can I change dynamicly the file name in the file path?

Tags: excel, vba, filenames, filepath, insert-into

I want to import multiple TXT files into excel (into the same sheet - every file has only 6 rows). How can I do the files path change in every cycle (I will take it in a for cycle)?

```
Sub openfile()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\HarrsionDavid\Desktop\\source\customer.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "customer.txt"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1250
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 9, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A1:C3").Selection
    Selection.Delete Shift:=x1Up
    Range("A1:C3").Selection
    Selection.Delete Shift:=x1Up
End Sub
```

In this question ([Import multiple text files into excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786126/import-multiple-text-files-into-excel)) there is an answer, but I need to change the file name only in the path, because the file names will be get from an other excel column. On Google and Stackoveflow I have no found anything.

Comment: Just wondering - I have noticed this `x1Up` problem in quite a lot of questions in StackOverflow. Where is it coming from initially? (To see what I mean, search the code for `x1Up`.)

Comment: @Vityata Good spot!

Comment: @Olly - Thanks. I see this too often here and there and I really don't know where is it coming from? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513779/run-time-error-1004 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102903/run-time-error-1004-excel-2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string variable for a file name, and append that to the hard coded filepath:

```
Sub openfile(ByVal sFileName As String)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\HarrsionDavid\Desktop\\source\" & sFileName, _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "customer.txt"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1250
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 9, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A1:C3").Selection
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1:C3").Selection
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Then call by passing the filename:

```
Sub TestOpenFile()
    openfile "customer.txt"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Write the paths in `Range("A1:A5")` and loop through them, passing them as a parameter to the `Sub OpenFile`.
2. Then in your code change the `C:\Users\HarrsionDavid\Desktop\\source` to the passed parameter.
3. Try to make your code better, by trying to avoid `Select` and `Activate` - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba):

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim paths As Variant        
    paths = Range("A1:A5")
    Dim singlePath As Variant

    For Each singlePath In paths
        OpenFile (singlePath)
    Next singlePath

End Sub

Public Sub OpenFile(singlePath As String)

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & singlePath, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        'more code...
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert another code to create a basic loop, and change one line in your current code as per below:

```
Public Path As String
Public rng As Range
Sub Loop_Through_Files()
'ensure that public path is the first line in this module literally at the very top
'set this as your first set of data
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Repeat:
Path = rng.Value
Call openfile
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
If IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then ' checks if the cell is blank and ends macro, ensure that after the last path there is a blank cell
Else
GoTo Repeat
End If
End Sub
```

This is your code slightly modified, i replaced your path with the word path.

```
Sub openfile()
'ensure that public path is the first line in this module literally at the very top
  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Path _
        , Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "customer.txt"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1250
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 9, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

  Range("A1:C3").Selection
  Selection.delete Shift:=x1Up
  Range("A1:C3").Selection
  Selection.delete Shift:=x1Up

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable which will store the path of the files. If you take it the "opening code" in an `if` you can open every file what you want (if the filenames are in the first column in excel).

```
Sub openfile()

    Dim Con As String

    For i = 3 To 400

    Con = "TEXT;" & Cells(1,4).Value & "\" & Cells(i,1).Value

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        Con _
        ,Destination:=Cells(i,2)
        .Name = Cells(i,1).Value
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    Next i

End Sub
```